# c# console keeps on in process

Tags: c#, forms, console

I am making a windows-form which contains a console. now when the console is openend and i later close either the console or the form( automaticly closes console too ) The proces of the console stays online when i look inside the taskmanager.

How is this possible? and why is this happening?

And, when i call the console it somehow doesn't get updated. this means
when i make any changes in the console inside visual studio, than save, start the program. It still uses the version BEFORE the save.

How is this possible, and why is this happening?

thank you

EDIT:
I have a seperate project in my solution called "parts' this is the console. I start i using

> Console = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Krijn\Desktop\CarWorks\Parts\bin\Debug\Parts");

Comment: How are you closing the console?

Comment: Re: The second part, you need to _compile_.

Comment: The console closes automaticly or either via close button. @James

Comment: What do you exactly mean, and how do i compile? @SLaks

Comment: Please post the code you use for starting the console process.

Comment: It has been posted. @MarkusSafar

Comment: Closing the form shouldn't "*automatically close the console*", it's a separate process. If you want to do that you need to explicitly do it e.g. [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I will give it a try, ill keep you updated. thank you for answering. @James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aleady mentioned you start a new process. The new process is independent from the one starting it. You need to terminate the started process yourself, I would suggest something like this:

```
Process consoleProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Krijn\Desktop\CarWorks\Parts\bin\Debug\Parts");

// Do some stuff here...

if (!consoleProcess.HasExited)
{
    // Terminate the process
    consoleProcess.Kill();
}

// Wait until the process is really terminated.
consoleProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Oh wow, this brought me to the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, don't mention it ;-)